# What does it mean when a html tag attribute include % in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, radio-button

```
<?php
_e( '<input type="radio" name="%1$s" id="%2$s" value="yes" data-required="%1$s">', $support_input_name, $support_input_id );
    _e( '<label for="%1$s">%2$s</label>', $support_input_id, u('yes_text') );
?>
```

What does it mean when we have `%2`as the name or id  for a radio button? (This is not my code but I need to make some modification on it.) I want to get the results for the radio button chosen; for that reason I need the name of the radio buttons.

[image]

Comment: Share the code off the function _e

Answer (score 0):

They are referencing the arguments at the end of the function.

```
_e( '<input type="radio" name="%1$s" id="%2$s" value="yes" data-required="%1$s">', $support_input_name, $support_input_id );
```

%1$s references $support_input_name and %2$s references $support_input_id. Whenever those values appear in the string, the variable data replaces them.

Comment: how can you tell without knowing the source code under the function _e